# Boxplotを条件ごとに作成する。

Tags: r

ggplot2を用いて、経時的なサンプルの変化を箱ひげ図で示したいと思っています。

以下のような手順で進めると、添付画像のように横軸のDayが反映されない箱ひげ図が出力されてしまいます。
Dayごとに箱ひげ図をまとめるには、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Boxplotに詳しい方、コメントを頂けないでしょうか？

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(easystats)

#サンプルデータの作成
A_X_value = as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 10))
A_Y_value = as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 30))
B_X_value = as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 15))
B_Y_value = as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 20))

Sample = c(rep("A", 60), rep("B", 60))
Feature = c(rep("X", 30), rep("Y", 30), rep("X", 30), rep("Y", 30))
Day = c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20), rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20))
Value = c(A_X_value, A_Y_value, B_X_value, B_Y_value)

test_box_DF = data.frame(Sample, Feature, Day, Value)

#boxplotの作成

gp_boxtest = ggplot(data = test_box_DF, aes(x = Day, y = Value, color = Feature)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ Sample) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing = grid::unit(1, "lines"), axis.text = element_text(colour = "black")) +
  labs(x="Day", y="Value") 

gp_boxtest
```

[image: 出力結果]

Answer (score 1):

「Dayごとに箱ひげ図にする」ためには `~ Day` を facet_wrap() に渡します

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse) 
pacman::p_load(easystats)
#サンプルデータの作成
A_X_value <- as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 10))
A_Y_value <- as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 30))
B_X_value <- as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 15))
B_Y_value <- as.numeric(rpois(30, lambda = 20))
Sample <- c(rep("A", 60), rep("B", 60))
Feature <- c(rep("X", 30), rep("Y", 30), rep("X", 30), rep("Y", 30))
Day <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20), rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20))
Value <- c(A_X_value, A_Y_value, B_X_value, B_Y_value)
# facet時のラベルに使うカラムを追加
test_box_DF <- tibble(Sample, Feature, Day, Value) %>% 
  mutate(day_label = paste("Day:", Day))

#boxplotの作成
gp_boxtest <- ggplot(test_box_DF, aes(x = Feature, y = Value, color = Sample)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~day_label)

gp_boxtest
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとう御座います。やりたいことは、Feasure X, Feature BのValue値をDayごとに箱ひげ図にする、ということでした。今回の場合、Dayが1, 2, 3と三つあるはずなのに、箱ひげ図が一つ（ご回答でも二つ）しか生成されず、また横軸のDayと関係ないところに描かれる点を何とかしたいと思っておりました。

Comment: すいません理解できました まず `facet_wrap(~Day)` にする所から初めてはいかがかと思います

Comment: 追加のコメントを誠にありがとう御座います。facet_wrap(~Sample)として、Featureごとに、横軸にDay、縦軸にvalueの箱ひげ図を描く、というのは、難しい（無理？）なのでしょうか？無理だとすれば、それはなぜなのか、今一つよくつかめず。。ご教示を頂きましたグラフでも良いですが、Featureごとの表示でも、類似の問題がおきているように思え（例えば、Day 1, 3では、Featureごとに箱ひげ図が出せてない？）、何とか原因を理解したい、と思っていました。もし、何かご存知でしたら、何卒宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

既に解決済みかもしれませんが，`Day` についても文字列で指定することで御希望の描画ができそうです。

```
## Day = c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20), rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20))
Day = c(rep('1', 20), rep('2', 20), rep('3', 20),
        rep('1', 20), rep('2', 20), rep('3', 20))
```

なお，作成したデータフレームを出力するとわかりますが，組み合せ可能な12（= 2 x 2 x 3）種類の行のうち (A, X, 3)， (A, Y, 1)，(B, X, 3)，(B, Y, 1) の4種類の行はないので箱ひげ図は8個になります。
[image: 描画出力]